# How to stretch text in CSS like microsoft word?

Tags: html, css

I want to stretch text (like ms-word) using CSS or some other possible technique.

Following CSS is not actually stretching anything:

```
font-stretch:ultra-expanded;
```

Please redirect me if I am wrong.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Its only supported in firefox and ie9+

Comment: By stretching do you mean: 1) Adding white space between words. 2) Adding white space between letters. 3) Making each letter broader. ... or a combination thereof ???

Comment: I don't know about ie but I checked it in the latest version of firefox which is not working

Comment: what about letter-spacing?

Comment: @Ole Sauffaus 3rd option making each letter broader

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting character width with css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262094/setting-character-width-with-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`font-stretch` (characters itself) can be achieved by css3's transform:scaleX() and transform:scaleY() properties in which dimension you want to stretch. 

Here is cross browsers compatible CSS:

```
-webkit-transform:scaleX(2);
-moz-transform:scaleX(2);
-ms-transform:scaleX(2);
-o-transform:scaleX(2);
transform:scaleX(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS Transforms, like

```css
h2 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  transform: scaleX(2);
}
```

```html
<h2>Stretched text</h2>
```

But usually distorting fonts is not a good idea. Probably it's better to look for a web font that initially looks as you need.

Comment: You would need vendor-prefixes for that to work ... like this: `-webkit-transform:scale(1,2);
-moz-transform:scale(1,2);
-ms-transform:scale(1,2);
-o-transform:scale(1,2);
transform:scale(1,2);`

Comment: @OleSauffaus, `-moz-transform` and `-o-transform` are not really needed anymore, all versions of Mozilla and Opera that are in practical use currently understand the unprefixed standard syntax. Only `-webkit-` may still be needed for mobile browsers like Android Browser 4.3-, and `-ms-` is yseful for just IE9.

Comment: I just realised that ... but still ... might come in handy for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the options in CSS:

```
.broader {
    letter-spacing:0.5em;
    word-spacing:1.5em;
    text-align: justify;/* Fills to parents borders */
}
```

`font-stretch` isn’t supported by others than IE+FireFox ... look here: http://caniuse.com/#search=font-stretch

Besides `font-stretch` won’t actually make any font wider, it will just substitute current font with a wider variant ... kinda like `font-style:bold/italic` does.

Comment: nice but I want to stretch the characters itself